# Reassigning column names after concatenating pandas series into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, rename

I have ***concatenated*** many **Pandas series'** together to create a **dataframe.**

```
datasize = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.count())
datasum = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.sum())
datamean = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.mean())
datastd = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.std())
df = pd.concat([datasize,datasum,datamean,datastd],axis=1)
```

The output of **df** is:

```
df
               estimate      estimate      estimate      estimate
Asia                  5  2.898666e+09  5.797333e+08  6.790979e+08
Australia             1  2.331602e+07  2.331602e+07           NaN
Europe                6  4.579297e+08  7.632161e+07  3.464767e+07
North America         2  3.528552e+08  1.764276e+08  1.996696e+08
South America         1  2.059153e+08  2.059153e+08           NaN
```

However, I would like to rename the columns in the following order as: **['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']**

I would also like to **title the index** as 'Continent'.

Could anybody give me any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead your solution use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

So change:

```
datasize = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.count())
datasum = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.sum())
datamean = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.mean())
datastd = Reducedset['estimate'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x.std())
df = pd.concat([datasize,datasum,datamean,datastd],axis=1)
df.columns = ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']
```

to:

```
Reducedset['estimate'] = pd.to_numeric(Reducedset['estimate'], errors='coerce')

df = (Reducedset.groupby(level=0)['estimate']
                .agg(['count','sum','mean','std'])
                .rename(columns={'count':'size'})
                .rename_axis('Continent'))
```

Or:

```
Reducedset['estimate'] = pd.to_numeric(Reducedset['estimate'], errors='coerce')

df = (Reducedset.groupby(level=0).agg(size =('estimate', 'count'),
                                      sum=('estimate', 'sum'),
                                      mean=('estimate', 'mean'),
                                      std =('estimate', 'std'))
                 .rename_axis('Continent'))
```

Comment: it gives me 'no numeric types to aggregate'. If we use the 2nd part of your solution, do we need to use the 1st part? How does the program know what 'count', 'sum', 'mean', 'std' mean (when as a string)?

Comment: I still get the error message: No numeric types to aggregate, but thanks for clarifying so far!

Comment: @Caledonian26 - so your solution working nice and my no? It is weird, because it should be. never mind, I edit answer with `Reducedset['estimate'] = pd.to_numeric(Reducedset['estimate'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
df.columns = ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']
```

To add name to index using [**`df.rename_axis`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

```
df.rename_axis('Continent')
```

Output:

```
                  size        sum         mean         std       
Continent               
Asia                  5  2.898666e+09  5.797333e+08  6.790979e+08
Australia             1  2.331602e+07  2.331602e+07           NaN
Europe                6  4.579297e+08  7.632161e+07  3.464767e+07
North America         2  3.528552e+08  1.764276e+08  1.996696e+08
South America         1  2.059153e+08  2.059153e+08           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

for index column title:

```
df.index.name='Continent'
```

for column names:

```
df.columns = ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']
```

Hope it helps..